# How to add a class to a button in a link

Tags: jquery

I want to change the existing class for the button and tooltip in the following link.  How can I do that?

```
 $("<a>")
              .attr("tabIndex", -1)
              .attr("title", "Show All Items")
              .tooltip(   //change class here)
              .appendTo(this.wrapper)
              .button({
                        //change class here
              })
              .removeClass("ui-corner-all")
              .addClass("custom-combobox-toggle")
              .mousedown(function () {
                  wasOpen = input.autocomplete("widget").is(":visible");
              })

.ButtonStyle { background-image: url('../Arrow_Down.gif'); margin: 0; border: outset; height: 22px; width: 20px; padding: 0; }
```

For the time being, the HTML rendered is as follows: please note that I want to change it.

[image]

Comment: Please add your HTML to the question.

Answer (score 1):

to add a class use:

```
buttonObj.addClass('class');
```

and to change style of any class:

```
$('.tooltip').css({/* new css values*/});
```

it would be better, if you show some fiddle or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your html is like this:

```
<form action="http://google.com">
    <input id="fooButton" type="submit" value="click me">
</form>
```

Your query will be:

```
$('#fooButton').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('fooClass');
});
```